# Magnetic Vector Potential Units question

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics

The units for the first equation do not agree with the definitions.  Does anyone know why?  Calculation or definitions used?

$$
\mathbf{B} = \nabla \times \mathbf{A}\,,\quad \mathbf{E} = -\nabla\phi - \frac{ \partial \mathbf{A} }{ \partial t }\,,
$$
$\Phi_B$ is $Vs$, $\mathbf B$ is $\frac {Vs} {m^2}$, $\mathbf A$ (per [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_vector_potential)) is $\frac {Vs} {m}$.  Taking the cross product is a number of partial derivatives that sum with the unit $\frac {Vs} {m}$, which is not equal to $\mathbf B$ being $\frac {Vs} {m^2}$, by a factor of $\frac 1 m$.

For the $\mathbf E$ the units agree with the definition, $V$.

Comment: Maybe the issue is that you think $E$ has units of Volts rather than V/m?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We know that $[E]=\frac{V}{m}$. Subsequently, $[\phi]=V$ and $[\frac{\partial \vec A}{\partial t}]=\frac{V}{m}$. Thus, $[\vec A]=\frac{V\cdot s}{m}$ and as you mentioned $[\vec B]=\frac{V\cdot s}{m^{2}}$. The issue is your interpretation of the $\nabla\times$ operation on a vector. This is not a cross product. It's the [curl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Del) operation which is in essence a spatial differentiation and in terms of dimensionality adds a $m^{-1}$ such that $[\vec B]=\frac{[\vec A]}{m}$.

Comment: For $\mathbf E = -\nabla\phi - \frac{ \partial \mathbf{A} }{ \partial t }$, when I substitute $[\phi]=V, [\frac{ \partial \mathbf{A} }{ \partial t }] = \frac V m$ this does not equal $[\mathbf E] = \frac V m$.

Comment: As explained in the answer and similar to the case of the curl, the gradient $\nabla$ is also essentially a first order spatial derivative, e.g., $E_{x}=-\partial \phi/\partial x$ which implies $[E]=[\phi]/m$.